# Using Git remote interactions in PHPStorm times out / waits indefinitely

Tags: git, github, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PHPStorm on Windows.
When using git (github) and trying to push to my remote branch the operation just animates the spinning circle for the operation and waits indefinitely.

I've noticed that in my process explorer a git.exe and git-remote-https.exe is launched, and stays alive with 0% CPU usage while this happens. Only way to quit this is to force quit the processes.

Tried removing the git repo and connecting anew, but the repo test fails.

Trying to push from command line works.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch Webstorm/PHPStorm with administrative privileges it will work.

My guess why this is:

Most likely the processes git.exe and git-remote-https.exe fails to do its work when they are spawned by PHPStorm without admin rights.

Update:
Most likely this was due to permissions being borked on my temp file folder.

Comment: Could be for a variety of reasons. Sounds like a bug though - you should report it as a bug, unless there's already a documented procedure for using ssh and you haven't followed it.